# Decrypt PGP message with private keys but forgotten passphrase

Tags: pgp, decryption

I forgot the passphrase of my PGP, but I have the private keys. Is there any "easy" method which doesn't take years to decrypt the PGP message?

Comment: You said "encrypt" throughout. I edited to "decrypt" for you.

Answer (score 2):

In case you used PGP Desktop > 9.7 and you did set up security questions, according to symantec you could recover your passphrase using the following steps:

https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.TECH149052.html

In case you used any other PGP Software please refer to its documentation on how to proceed in case of a forgotten password. In case the software you used doesnt contain a passphrase reset procedure, you are most likely left with the chances of brute forcing your password (in case you remember its symbol pattern that would be helpful in generating a wordlist).

In most cases, you would need to either generate a reliable wordlist based on what you remember, or in case you are unable to build a decent and reliable, easily crackable symbol pattern you would just need to forget about it. Overall that's the idea of the encryption, not to be able to decrypt it unless you **posses** the key and **know** the password. That's the basic principle of several factor authentication - not to be able to decrypt sensitive data even if you have a piece of the puzzle, you need to have all the factors to assemble the pieces into one sensible unit.

Please refer to the answer in the folowing thread:
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/163514/forgot-openpgp-keys-passphrase-can-i-recover-key-or-files-somehow